# C# Reflection Interface Type and Unity

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

hope someone can help. I use Unity and app.config to dynamically load and run methods in certain assemblies. In our main application I used to do something like ...

```
var ourProcess = container.Resolve<IProcessing>(new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("parameter1", value1) });
ourProcess.ExecuteProcess(parameterValues); 
// parameterValues a string list, all of my processes use this main calling mechanism.
// there are many other interfaces i a number of other assemblies along with IProcessing
```

However in the main application I need a reference to the IProcessing interface and that's of little use because if I add another processing assembly I don't want to reference said new assembly in the main application, rebuild, retest and redistribute, I just want Unity to resolve and call as appropriate.

I've tried using reflection along the lines of ...

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("CompName.Application.Processing.dll");
foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    if (type.GetInterface("IProcessing") != null)
    {
        var ourProcess = container.Resolve<type> (new ResolverOverride[] { new ParameterOverride("parameter1", value1) });
        oSummary = ourProcess.ExecuteProcess(parameterValues);
    }
}
// at runtime we will know the strings "CompName.Application.Processing.dll" and "IProcessing"
```

However at compile time we get the "'type' is a variable but is used like a Type", fair enough.

I've tried typeof(type), type.GetType() and Type(type) to no avail, all resulting in different compiler errors.

So, the question is how can I use the string name of the interface I require to instantiate and run a process in a non-referenced assembly resolved and loaded by Unity? I'm a little new to Unity and this is the first time using reflection so please go easy on me. I do feel though that this should be relatively easy and feel I am missing something fundemental.

I have searched for the previous few hours and tried one or two things but none have given me the results I need. It would be time consuming to remove my Unity driven code throughout the systems.

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The problem with how you call `Resolve` is because you have to use a concrete type with generics.  If you don't have a concrete type, you'll need to build a `MethodInfo` using `container`'s type, and fill in the type parameters with `MakeGenericMethod`.  I'm not sure if Unity supports it, but Autofac is able to get an `IEnumerable` from it's `Resolve` method, containing one of everything that implements your type.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the Type of the class, you could just use

```
var processor = Activator.CreateInstance(type, param[] object args) as IProcessing;
```

Edit:
or you could use "dynamic", if you are willing to take the performance penalty coming with that. And if you are ok with the fact, that you won't have any Intellisense help, during the writing of your code.

```
var processor = Activator.CreateInstance(type, param[] object args) as dynamic;
processor.ExecuteProcess(parameterValues);
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, as mentioned I cannot reference the IProcessing type directly, to do so I would have to include a reference of the assembly containing the IProcessing type into my main assembly. This is soemthing I do not wish to do.

Comment: but you already loaded the assembly into memory with Assembly.LoadFrom("..."), you dont need to add the reference when using runtime "linking". You need, however, the IProcessing in a referenced assembly.

Comment: Hi Andreas, "You need, however, the IProcessing in a referenced assembly..." This is what I am trying to get away from. Ta, K

Comment: Can't you at least have the Interface in a referenced assembly? How is the other code working with instances of IProcessing, if you don't have at least the Interface referenced? Or are you always using "dynamic"?

Comment: Hi Andreas, I'm hoping this to be totally dynamic but looking into it further I may have to refactor so all my interfaces resides in a single assembly. Currenly they are scattered between assemblies. K

Comment: you could use the dynamic "type"... see edit, but it comes with a price